# Theoretical approach of the quantum CNOT gate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Let's $ |\psi \rangle $ be $ \sqrt{1} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{2}{8} \\\ \frac{6}{8} \end{pmatrix} $, $ |\phi \rangle $ $ = \sqrt{1} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{3}{4} \\\ \frac{1}{4} \end{pmatrix} $,

and $ |\omega \rangle $ = |$ \psi \rangle $ $ \otimes $ |$ \phi \rangle $ = 
$ \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{\frac{2}{8}} \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}} \\\ \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}} \end{pmatrix} \\\ \sqrt{\frac{6}{8}} \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}} \\\ \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}} \end{pmatrix} \end{pmatrix} = $
$ \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \\\ \frac{1}{4} \\\ \frac{3}{4} \\\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \end{pmatrix} $
 be our 2-qubit quantum state.

Here is my question:
If a do a CNOT on $ \omega $:
 $ |\omega_{NOT} \rangle = CNOT(\omega) =  $ $ \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \\\ \frac{1}{4} \\\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \\\ \frac{3}{4} \end{pmatrix} $

Now, $ \omega $ being the "old" system, and $ \omega_{NOT} $ our new system:  $ \delta_{\omega} \neq \delta_{\omega_{NOT}} $  where $ \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\\ \beta \\\ \delta \\\ \gamma \end{pmatrix} $

The chances of |$ \omega \rangle $ being either |$ 00 \rangle $ or |$ 01 \rangle $ are the same as $ 
\omega_{NOT} $. But the chances of being |$ 10 \rangle $ or |$ 11 \rangle $ have changed.
But theses last two chances should only change if the control bit ($ \psi $) is $ = $ |$ 1 \rangle $ thus the control has $ \frac{6}{8} $ chances to be |$ 1 \rangle $

I Would like to know what i am misconceiving.
Thanks

Comment: The tensor product you've quoted is wrong (it's not the tensor product of the vectors you quote above it), and the line starting $\alpha |\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\rangle+\cdots$ is plain word salad - it doesn't mean anything (you seem to be confusing coefficients with basis-vector labels). That makes it impossible to even get near the CNOT parts of your question.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Sorry for the "salad" x).. I really don't see where the tensor product is wrong.. :/ I added one more step to make it clearer.

Comment: The tensor product is now correct - you're just misreporting the two initial states. This is now answerable, though.